# CHR: managing "constraint stores"

Tags: prolog, constraints, store, chr

Is there a way to manage Constraint stores in CHR ?
What I have in mind ?

Let say I do a query. I want the result set, set aside (may be with different scope than user:) for reuse OR as start for a different run, OR just for inspection.

Another thing is what do you do if you get hundreds or thousands results. you can not really manage them on the screen. How do you debug those scenarios ?

Is there a way to assert() the results or part of the results as a Prolog facts ?

==========

One way of doing it I figured out is to add prolog clause that assert whatever you want, but still is not storing aside CStore ;(

```
dup(X,Y) :-  assertz(via(X,Y)).

...head.. <=> ...body..., dup(X,Y).
```

not very handy, but at least something ...